# Counting the Number of Points in an Algebraic Variety

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, combinatorial-number-theory

How can we count the number of points in

$$S = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z_m}^2: x^2+ky^2 = c\}$$ where $k,c$ are some positive integers?

Comment: You can easily find (poor) bounds. For instance, the cardinal has to be less than $\frac{c}{k}$ because $x^2 >0 \Rightarrow y \leq \sqrt{ \frac{c}{k}}$. You might be able to adapt the method used to generate the Pythagorean triple: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple

Comment: That argument doesn't go through in $\mathbb{Z}_m$.

Answer (score 1):

If k is fixed and c varies, it is a beatiful and imporatant problem.

---

For k=1, Jacobi is the first one who gaves the formula :

$4[D_{(4,1)}(c) - D_{(4,3)}(c)]$,

where $D_{(4,1)}(c)$ stands for the number of (positive) divisors of c which is congruent to 1 modulue 4,

and $D_{(4,3)}(c)$ stands for the number of (positive) divisors of c which is congruent to 3 modulue 4.

---

For the case k=2 we have a similar formula:

$2[D_{(8,1)}(c)+D_{(8,3)}(c)-D_{(8,5)}(c)-D_{(8,7)}(c)]$,

where $D_{(8,1)}(c)$ stands for the number of (positive) divisors of c which is congruent to 1 modulue 8,

and $D_{(8,3)}(c)$ stands for the number of (positive) divisors of c which is congruent to 3 modulue 8,

and $D_{(8,5)}(c)$ stands for the number of (positive) divisors of c which is congruent to 5 modulue 8,

and $D_{(8,7)}(c)$ stands for the number of (positive) divisors of c which is congruent to 7 modulue 8

---

For the cases k=3, 7 we have a similar formula, you can find them in ramanujan lost notebooks.
In all these cases the class group is trivial, but when it is not it has a wild behavior.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. :) Please for your math via [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)